# How to transform the content of a two-columns data frame based on row number of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data frames. One is a data frame that only contains names

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- structure(list(name1 = c("B2m", "Itm2b", "Itm2b"), name2 = c("Cd44", 
"Atp1b2", "Sppl2b")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df1
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name1 name2 
  <chr> <chr> 
1 B2m   Cd44  
2 Itm2b Atp1b2
3 Itm2b Sppl2b
```

Another is a data frame that stores all names above:

```
df2 <- structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("Atp1b2", 
"B2m", "Cd44", "Itm2b", "Sppl2b"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  name  
  <fct> 
1 B2m   
2 Cd44  
3 Atp1b2
4 Sppl2b
5 Itm2b
```

What I want to transform `df1` into a numerical pair based on row number in `df2` yielding:

```
name1 name2
1     2
5     3
5     4
```

How can I do that conveniently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
sapply(df1, match, df2$name)

     name1 name2
[1,]     1     2
[2,]     5     3
[3,]     5     4
```

Or same thing using tidyverse:

```
library(purrr)

map_df(df1, match, df2$name)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name1 name2
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     5     3
3     5     4
```